# Format string vulneratbility code redirected to main()

Tags: c, return, gdb, exploit, format-string

This is the format4 protostar challenge.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>

int target;

void hello()
{
  printf("You win....\n");
  //exit(1);
}

void vuln()
{
  char buffer[512];
  fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
  printf(buffer);
  exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  vuln();
}
```

The disassembly is

```
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00005555555551bc <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x00005555555551bd <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x00005555555551c0 <+4>:     sub    rsp,0x10
   0x00005555555551c4 <+8>:     mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
   0x00005555555551c7 <+11>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rsi
=> 0x00005555555551cb <+15>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x00005555555551d0 <+20>:    call   0x555555555178 <vuln>
   0x00005555555551d5 <+25>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x00005555555551da <+30>:    leave  
   0x00005555555551db <+31>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) disass vuln
Dump of assembler code for function vuln:
   0x0000555555555178 <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x0000555555555179 <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x000055555555517c <+4>:     sub    rsp,0x200
   0x0000555555555183 <+11>:    mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rip+0x2ec6]        # 0x555555558050 <stdin@@GLIBC_2.2.5>
   0x000055555555518a <+18>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x200]
   0x0000555555555191 <+25>:    mov    esi,0x200
   0x0000555555555196 <+30>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x0000555555555199 <+33>:    call   0x555555555050 <fgets@plt>
   0x000055555555519e <+38>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x200]
   0x00005555555551a5 <+45>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x00005555555551a8 <+48>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x00005555555551ad <+53>:    call   0x555555555040 <printf@plt>
   0x00005555555551b2 <+58>:    mov    edi,0x1
   0x00005555555551b7 <+63>:    call   0x555555555060 <exit@plt>
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) disass hello
Dump of assembler code for function hello:                                                                                                                           
   0x0000555555555165 <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x0000555555555166 <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000555555555169 <+4>:     lea    rdi,[rip+0xe94]        # 0x555555556004
   0x0000555555555170 <+11>:    call   0x555555555030 <puts@plt>
   0x0000555555555175 <+16>:    nop
   0x0000555555555176 <+17>:    pop    rbp
   0x0000555555555177 <+18>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

The instructions when the execution reaches `You win...`

```
(gdb) x/30i $rip
=> 0x555555555169 <hello+4>:    lea    rdi,[rip+0xe94]        # 0x555555556004
   0x555555555170 <hello+11>:   call   0x555555555030 <puts@plt>
   0x555555555175 <hello+16>:   nop
   0x555555555176 <hello+17>:   pop    rbp
   0x555555555177 <hello+18>:   ret    
   0x555555555178 <vuln>:       push   rbp
   0x555555555179 <vuln+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x55555555517c <vuln+4>:     sub    rsp,0x200
   0x555555555183 <vuln+11>:    mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rip+0x2ec6]        # 0x555555558050 <stdin@@GLIBC_2.2.5>
   0x55555555518a <vuln+18>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x200]
   0x555555555191 <vuln+25>:    mov    esi,0x200
   0x555555555196 <vuln+30>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x555555555199 <vuln+33>:    call   0x555555555050 <fgets@plt>
   0x55555555519e <vuln+38>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x200]
   0x5555555551a5 <vuln+45>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x5555555551a8 <vuln+48>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x5555555551ad <vuln+53>:    call   0x555555555040 <printf@plt>
   0x5555555551b2 <vuln+58>:    mov    edi,0x1
   0x5555555551b7 <vuln+63>:    call   0x555555555060 <exit@plt>
   0x5555555551bc <main>:       push   rbp
   0x5555555551bd <main+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x5555555551c0 <main+4>:     sub    rsp,0x10
   0x5555555551c4 <main+8>:     mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
   0x5555555551c7 <main+11>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rsi
   0x5555555551cb <main+15>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x5555555551d0 <main+20>:    call   0x555555555178 <vuln>
   0x5555555551d5 <main+25>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x5555555551da <main+30>:    leave  
   0x5555555551db <main+31>:    ret    
   0x5555555551dc:      nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
```

In this program I commented the `exit(1)` in `hello()` function and found that while the flow of execution is redirected to hello using format string vulnerability, the return address of `hello()` stack frame points to the beginning of the `main()` function. It prints the `you win...` statement for a while and eventually the program crashes with seg fault. Should it not end the program since the return type of `hello()` is `void`? And why did it return to the start of the program? My machine is kali linux running on virtualbox.

Comment: Probably because it just did a jump to `hello()` rather than calling it as a function.

Comment: You should use a debugger to see what happens exactly

Comment: I did got overwrite. So yeah it jumps instead of calling `hello() `, but why did it return to `main() `

Comment: @Kingslayer you need to look at the generated assembly code. Anything else is guessing.

Comment: @Jabberwocky generated assembly code of `hello() ` prints the you win... statement and returns. Why does it return to `main() `?

Comment: @Kingslayer don't describe what your code does, but show the complete generated assembly code in your question. What is your platform/compiler/IDE/OS?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I have included the disassembly

Comment: A called function doesn't return _to_ somewhere, it just _returns_. The destination is whatever is on the stack, so you need to examine the stack to see where it will go.

Comment: The stack contains the return address `0x5555555551bc`. Also since I did GOT overwrite, exit@plt is called and the execution jumps to `hello()`